# 'EOFError: EOF when reading a line' while parsing argv in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, arguments

I am running my program on Jupyter-notebook

```
%%file ex14.py
from sys import argv
script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '
print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script))
print ("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")
print ("Do you like me %s?" % user_name)
likes = (input(prompt))
print ("Where do you live %s?" % user_name)
lives = input(prompt)
print ("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = input(prompt)
```

In the next cell

```
%%!
python ex14.py argument
```

After this program is not asking for the user inputs. Any guidance?

`The same program is executing fine in terminal`

Full error displayed in Jupyter

```
`["Hi argument, I'm the ex14.py script.",
 "I'd like to ask you a few questions.",
 'Do you like me argument?',
 '> Traceback (most recent call last):',
 '  File "ex15.py", line 7, in <module>',
 '    likes = (input(prompt))',
 'EOFError: EOF when reading a line']`
```

Comment: Your script works fine on my computer:  
`Y:\Scripts\Python\Facebookbot>python test.py bendik`  
`Hi bendik, I'm the test.py script.`  
`I'd like to ask you a few questions.`  
`Do you like me bendik?`  
`> quite good`    
`Where do you live bendik?`  
`> Oslo`  
`What kind of computer do you have?`  
`> a black one`

Comment: Insider of running current cell alone, run all the cell. when you running that particular cell its scope is with in that alone not with the complete page or cell. -Thanks partha

Answer (score 0):

Because in Jupyter Notebook

```
%%!
python ex14.py argument
```

return your value in List. Use this `%run` instead of `%%!
    python`

```
%run ex14.py argument
```